# How can I enable spell checker in google colab (colab operates on linux OS)?

Tags: linux, google-colaboratory, spell-checking

Can we enable spell checker for markdown cells in google colab in any way? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way of doing so directly within Google Colaboratory, however a usable workaround might be to install a third party spell-checking browser plug-in such as Grammarly or another similar plug-in that works with your preferred browser, I know this probably wasn't the answer you where looking for, but I'm not aware of any better solutions, I truly apologize! But I hope this was at least somewhat helpful!
Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: I have the Grammarly extension on my firefox, though it does raise any alert on google-colab.

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), you can open your ipynb files in it, and it will highlight any spelling errors.

PyCharm professional edition was used to test this.