# Does Google Colaboratory have Spell Checker for text?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I was wondering if there is any way to utilize spell checker in my markdown cells in Google Colab?

Thank you

Comment: Also asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61210080/how-can-i-enable-spell-checker-in-google-colab-colab-operates-on-linux-os. There appears to be no way as of now